# How to add php to a linux (ubuntu) server already running nginx + gunicorn + django

Tags: ubuntu, php, nginx, django, gunicorn

I have been running a django app on nginx using gunicorn on Ubuntu (now version 12.04) for some time now, and have been pleased with the results. My issue is that I have inherited a php site which I want to run on the same server.

Can anyone give me some advice on what might be the best way to add php to my server setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `sudo apt-get install php-fpm`
2. Set up your new virtual host.
3. Enjoy.